# Func<T,T> action as a parameter for a function with <T>, and how to write the body?

Tags: c#

I have a class as follows. I just want to get the function `testa` and `testb` to get same result, testa has explicit type string with it, while generic type is defined for `testb`:

```
public class testclass
{
    public void testa(Func<String, String> action)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(action("what?"));
    }

    public void testall()
    {
        testa(tc =>
        {
            return tc;
        });

        testb<string>(tc =>
        {
            return tc;
        });
    }

    public void testb<T>(Func<T, T> action)
    {

         **//How to write the body here to get the same result as testa do
         //like action("abc");?**
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry to spam you on this question. If you undelete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171209/what-xxx-means-in-a-linux-shell, I was working on an answer that I'd like to share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont know what `T` is in `testb`, so you cant provide a concretete value, except `default(T)`:

```
public void testb<T>(Func<T, T> action)
{
    action(default(T)); // null for reference types, 0 for ints, doubles, etc    
}
```

Another option would be to provide the test value to `testb`

```
public void testb<T>(Func<T, T> action, T testValue)
{
    action(testValue);        
}

public void testall()
{
    testa(tc =>
    {
        return tc;
    });

    testb<string>(tc =>
    {
        return tc;
    }, "abc"); // now same result as testa
}
```

A third option, is to provide the constraint `new()` to `T`, and then you could construct one:

```
public void testb<T>(Func<T, T> action) where T : new()
{
    action(new T());        
}
```

---

Little sidenote: As commented, `action` is a usually name given to a function expression which has no return (ie `Action<T>` or `Action<string>` etc). It makes no difference to your code, but may confuse other programmers. We're a pedantic lot!

Comment: It's a little funny to call the `Func<T, T>` variable `action`. :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov of course you're right. My preference is `func` but just sticking to the OP's original code to save confusion.